# Uncaught TypeError: myFormRef.submit is not a function, I tried to make my textarea in React submit the value with the key Enter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textarea, submit

I tried to make my textarea input in React submit the value with the key Enter, but I got this error and I don't know why this is happend:

Error Message

[image: 1]

This is my function to catch the key:

```js
const myFormRef = useRef();


const onEnterPress = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(myFormRef.submit());
        }
 }
```

This one is the Form with textarea:

```js
 <Form id="myForm" ref={myFormRef} onSubmit={sendMessege}>
                <TextareaAutosize
                    className='text_input'
                    placeholder='Digite algo aqui'
                    type="text"
                    value={formValue}
                    onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)}
                    disabled={!user}
                    minRows={3}
                    maxRows={6}
                    onKeyDown={onEnterPress}
                />
 </Form>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: shouldn't you use  `console.log(myFormRef.current.submit());` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `current` from the reference.

Please try:

```
console.log(myFormRef?.current?.submit());
```

Comment: It works! but this refresh the whole page, how can I just submit this without refresh the page?

Comment: Then you maybe should consider not using useRef? but that is a different question than the one you asked here. If it worked, please consider marking it as solved, there is a check icon next to the answer.